# Forcing multiple JAXB namespace prefixes for packages generated with XJC

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

A project requires we export a bunch of data following a list of many public well-known XSD files, for which we have a bunch of packages originally generated with XJC. By default, the marshaller loads all namespaces from the context and declares them, but these declarations are not sorted and can randomly change between any execution and the next. This was making testing and validating needlessly hard.

I wanted to force certain prefixes on those namespaces, but no proposed solution if found here was helping. We're using Java17 and all relevant suggestions were 10 or so years old.

The project is quite fragile and running XJC again is not exactly feasible, but nevertheless I am somewhat forbidden to touch any auto-generated sources, so I have to work around that.

What I managed to come up with is a fake package containing a `package-info.java` with a bunch of `@XmlNs` declarations and a class to trick the marshaller into loading my package.

This is my `package-info.java`:

```java
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(xmlns = {
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd", prefix = "gmd"),
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco", prefix = "gco"),
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", prefix = "xlink"),
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx", prefix = "gmx"),
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2", prefix = "gml"),
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts", prefix = "gts"),
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv", prefix = "srv")
})
package org.example.fake;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
```

This is my `NamespaceFixer.java`:

```java
package org.example.fake;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

/**
 * Load this into the marshaller to force our namespaces, @see package-info.java
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Namespace_fixer", propOrder = {})
public class NamespaceFixer {
}
```

When I create the marshaller, I add an additional class to the context:

```java
[...]
Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(//
    [...],
    NamespaceFixer.class, //
    [...]
).createMarshaller();
[...]
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?